# where can we write vbscript for testing of software?

Tags: automated-testing

I am new in automation testing and I don't know how to start writing scripts for test cases.  Can anybody tell me where I can write scripts for test cases and how? Give me some examples too.

Comment: Use QTP if you want to write test cases in VBscript.

Comment: It highly depends on what you're planning to test: Web site, desktop application (which GUI framework?), console utility, COM component...

Answer (score 1):

To automate using VBScript you have a few options that I know of:

- **QTP** - this is the "Gold standard" tool and is entirely VBScript-based. It's also extremely expensive.
- **TestComplete** - this is one of the cheaper big box tools. TC supports multiple script languages including VBScript

You can also build your own using classic ASP or the Windows Scripting Host if you wish.

Advice on how to start writing tests and examples isn't going to be terribly useful to you until you've done some more research: automated test cases are *extremely* variable depending on what exactly they're testing. I've written everything from completely headless API tests to tests that install the latest version of a Windows application, restore a known database, log in as a known user and perform a sequence of events before closing out and comparing the state of the database against a baseline.

I'd recommend working with an automation tool and using the tutorials provided until you understand how everything fits together. Then if you have more specific questions you can ask them here.